# convert string to integer LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new in Linq. The error(conversion from string "SYMBOL" to type integer is not valid) comes in the line : ' r("SYMBOL") = q!SYMBOL.ToString'. Please help

```
Dim tblBhavNSEFO As DataTable = gbl_dsBhavNSEFO.Tables(0)
Dim tblSource As New DataTable
tblSource.Columns.Add("SYMBOL", GetType(String))

Dim tblsymbols As DataTable = (From s In tblBhavNSEFO _
                       Where s!INSTRUMENT = strCondition _
                       Order By s!SYMBOL Ascending _
                       Select s).CopyToDataTable
Dim filter = From f In tblsymbols _
           Select f!SYMBOL Distinct

If filter.Count > 0 Then
    For Each q In filter
        Dim r = tblSource.NewRow()
        r("SYMBOL") = q!SYMBOL.ToString
        tblSource.Rows.Add(r)
    Next
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this code does not even compile with Option Strict On... Anyway, the problem seems to be that there is one `!SYMBOL` too many (you already reduce to `!SYMBOL` in `filter`).

Comment: I just want the "SYMBOL" field of table tblbhavnsefo to be distinct and then store all the records into new table with same field name. If there mistake in code then please modify

Comment: `filter` already reduces your list of datarows to a list of whatever-datatype-symbol-is. In other words: `q` already contains your symbol, not a datarow, so there's no need to `!SYMBOL` it.

Comment: Yes u were right. Thanks a lot. It is working now without writing !SYMBOL. Thanks again

Comment: That's good to know! I added the conclusion as an answer, so that the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: Make sure you have `Option Strict On`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop variable `q` already contains the symbol (you projected on `f!SYMBOL` in the definition of `filter`). Thus, adding `!SYMBOL` to `q` is not necessary.